# Why does the 'Active: today' on the side have a link?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

On this question: [Can you buy specific cards with gold?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/247827/can-you-buy-specific-cards-with-gold), if you  hover around the "today" next to the "active" part of the sidebar, it can be clicked as a link.

In this case, this one: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/247832/100298

Is this to show the user the most recent activity? or is it a bug?

Comment: You clicked a link labeled "active", with text indicating the time of the latest activity and a URL that ends with "?lastactivity", and it brought you to the latest activity on the question. What do you think is the bug here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is intended to bring the user to the most recent activity of a post, yes. It is not a bug.